# What does this mean to you if you were to see an application named "Japanese 語"?

Tags: meaning, kanji

My friend is creating a word card application to help people memorize Japanese words / Kanji.  The subject of what to call the application came up and he asked me for some suggestions. One of the requirements is that it's a very simple name with the word Japanese in English and then something else.

I suggested "Japanese 語" be the name of the application and I would like to get some input from the people here.

I already looked up the meaning of 語 but what I would like to know is does it look totally confusing or make some sense with the English word "Japanese" before it.

Comment: I can clearly understand the meaning but it sounds a bit awkward. And since the 'ese' part of Japanese means 語 anyway, how about just "Japan語" (Japango). It sounds snappier. By the way opinion based questions are off-topic on this site so the question will probably be closed.

Comment: `the 'ese' part of Japanese means 語` [*-ese* is used as a suffix to form adjectives and nouns describing things and characteristics of a city, region, or country](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ese). As a noun, *Japanese* means *those things of Japan*, and can only be interpreted as「語」if the context is clear. Comprehensive references such as encyclopedias refer to 日本語 as *Japanese language*, not just *Japanese* - I'm rather surprised at the interpretations here reading "Japanese 語" as *Japanese -ese*, when my first impression is that it should be read as just *Japanese language*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it's indeed confusing at least to native Japanese speakers.

- 語 meaning *word* is not really common outside academic contexts. Words listed on a word card/list are usually called 単語 by Japanese people who study foreign languages.
- 語 is also a suffix meaning *language* or *-ese*. For example 日本 means *Japan* and 日本語 means *Japanese*. When I see "Japanese 語", I can't help reading it as something weird like "Japanese-ese".

"Japanese 単語" would be at least not confusing.